# Estimation equation for multiple events in an event study

Tags: regression, linear-regression, equation, lm, estimation

I have a dataset of many companies' stock price and I am doing an event study. I want to write an estimation equation of the regression I do on them. I have an event window on 11 days:

[image]

D is a binary variable that takes on 1 for every day in the event window.
Should I write e.g. (t-5) in the subscript, or is it right how it is now?
And should there be both i and t in the outcome variable (y)?

The equation should show that I get an estimate of each day in the event window.

Answer (score 0):

Your definition of D doe does not make sense, given your formula. You must define a binary variable D_i for i=-5,.., 5 that is 1 for event day i, if you want to estimate the effect for each event day separately. Look at this example ([Pre-Testing in a DiD Setup using the did Package](https://bcallaway11.github.io/did/articles/pre-testing.html)
) of the DID R package where an Event Study regression with your setting in detail is applied.

Another possibility would be to go the "classical" way of performing an Event Study as described [Introduction Event Study Methodology](https://www.eventstudytools.com/introduction-event-study-methodology) and [Expected Return Models](https://www.eventstudytools.com/expected-return-models).